# Adding weights when using lmfit to fit a 3D line on a cloud of points

Tags: python, least-squares, lmfit

I am using the following code to fit a 3D line on a cloud of 3D points.
I am using a least squares method of **lmfit** to minimize.

I need to **add weights to different points**, but do not know how to do it when **using an array** (and **not a scalar**) distance output. The problem when using scalar is that the it is not as good as when using an array. I assume because of a larger number of variables.

So the question is -  is there a way to **add weights for each element of array to the minimizer**? 
Using something like Nelder w/scaral input does not perform the 3D fit well.

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter,report_fit,fit_report, Minimizer, printfuncs
import numpy as np

#parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('y1',   value= 0)
params.add('x0',   value= 129)
params.add('x1',   value= 0)
params.add('y0',   value= 129)
params.add('y1',   value= 0)

#function calculating point-line distance
def fun(params,x,y,z):
    x0 = params['x0'].value; x1 = params['x1'].value; y0 = params['y0'].value; y1 = params['y1'].value

    distance = []
    #parametric equations
    v0 = np.array([x0, y0, 0])
    v1 = np.array([x0+x1,y0+ y1, 1])

    #for loop over all the 3D points to calculate distance
    for point in range(len(x)):
        p = np.array([x[point], y[point], z[point]])
        distance.append(np.linalg.norm(np.cross(v0-p,v0-v1)))       
    return distance

result = minimize(fun, params,args=(x,y,z))
print(fit_report(result))

theta = np.arccos(1/ np.sqrt(result.params['x1']*result.params['x1']+result.params['y1']*result.params['y1']+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you read the documentation on how to write an objective function ([this link](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#fit-func-label) as provided in one of your other questions)? If so, which part of the description there is not clear and/or what did you try and didn't work?

In your example you generate an array called `distance`, which effectively is the same as `(model-data)` in the documentation. What you want to add here is `eps`, which will scale the residual by the uncertainty in the data.

Comment: I want to add my list of weights, and not use statistical uncertainty of data. 

It is easy to do for a scalar. My issue here however is that using a scalar and array does not produce the same result - although it should.

Comment: you should be able to just add a list of weights, in that case eps should just be 1/weights. It is not clear from your question if/why using a scalar or an array do not produce the same results as you don't give a minimal working example with the output for both scenarios.

Comment: So basically if I have a 1D array of weight, I can also simply output from the fun function distance X weights array? No need to use eps?